# Can't get geo fixes to Android emulator

Tags: android, gps, emulation

I'm trying to send geo fixes to the Android Emulator in Eclipse. It has been working in some locations, but now it never works. I've tried targeting different platforms, setting the time zone in the correct emulator, changing the locale to English (US), wiping the user data in the emulator, used both telnet geo fix command and the DDMS.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunatley no. Instead, I enabled debugging on device in the manifest file. The advantage, besides that I get the real geo fix, is that it starts upp much faster. When ever I needed to use the emulator I wrote some hard-coded geo fix in the code.

Comment: Could you give more details : setup (AVD, target Android version), code, error messages?...

Answer (score 5):

If your AVD version is API level 9, (2.3 emulator), then it appears to be a known bug

[onLocationChanged(Location location) method does not work in google API 9 platfom 2.3](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13262&q=geo%20fix&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

I've got two apps that work fine in 2.1 and 3.0, but one is reluctant to install under 2.3, when it does, geo fix doesn't work.. The other is installed and again geo fix doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your emulator's name is selected under Devices in DDMS.
And also occasionally ADB fails so the commands don't get sent to the emulator so you have to restart the dev environmeneclipse and adb.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very problem in the Java bootcamp I was teaching last week. This is a known bug in API level 9.

Your best bet is to connect a device and test on an actual device.  Once we did that we could see on the map the actual building we were in at the time!

I also recommend testing on the device for camera applications as the interface to test camera apps on the emulator is clunky..