# how to make getLastKnownLocation work on emulator

Tags: android, geolocation

Requirement of the application is to get the lat,lon from the mobile. I want to test the samething on emulator. But getLastKnownLocation gives null value . Could you please suggest some workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem: [Can't get geo fixes to Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064055/cant-get-geo-fixes-to-android-emulator)