# How to obtain the GPS position of the user and actualice a textview everytime the position has changed?

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to make a simple activity that reads the GPS position of the user and actualices a simple textview everytime the position of the user changes.

I find some examples en google but all of them are not nice examples, because only capture the position of the user ONE time, and i need that the textview get's actualiced everytime the position changes with the new latitude and longitude of the user.

I tryed to do a thread but it fails and i think it is not necesary to do a thread, im in the wrong way.

Code examples are welcome

EDIT: i'm adding the solution proposed by the user NickT. **This solution fails.** I dont know why but only actualizes two times the textview, with the two first GPS values that i pass to the emulator with DDMS.... after this the thextview isn't getting actualiced more times... ¿why?. I make a breakpoint in onLocationChanged, and it only get's called the first two times i send a gps positiones... but never more. ¿what is happening?

```
public class GpsMiniActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

private LocationManager mLocMgr;
private TextView tv1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout rl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout ll= new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setContentView(rl);
    rl.addView(ll);

    tv1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    ll.addView(tv1);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            500, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    tv1.setText("Lat " +   location.getLatitude() + " Long " + location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute minimum example:

```
public class GpsMiniActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    private LocationManager mLocMgr;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                500, 0, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv.setText("Lat " +   location.getLatitude() + " Long " + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

}
```

You'll also need permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in your manifest and a Textview id tv1 in main.xml

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will test, but i need it without implementing LocationListener, how to do it without implementing it?

Comment: The LocationListener is what detects the location changes. I can't see how it would work otherwise.

Comment: my class doesn't have to implement locationlistener, i'm sure there is anothr way to do it, without implementing it, how to do it?

Comment: ok i test your method and it fails, it only actualices the two first GPS positions that i pass to the emulator with DDMS.... later doesn't actualice the textview. Note that i have to made a minor change to your code, i have to declare the tv in other zone of the code, out of the listener, i can't do with the tv declared on your listener. Why? because i need to not use xml layout files. I will paste my code editing my question, test it on your eclipse and you will check that it fails and only receives two GPS positions and no one more

Comment: I make a breakpoint in onLocationChanged, and it only get's called the first two times i send a gps positiones... but never more. ¿what is happening?

Comment: If you emulator is API level 9, then there is a known bug with it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064055/cant-get-geo-fixes-to-android-emulator. Try it on level 7

Comment: is on API lvel 3, btw i tested it on the street and it works perfect!!!!!!! but i need to do it without implementing LocationListener, please can you change your code to do it without implementing it?

Comment: please can you change your code to do it without implementing it?