# Gps doesn't work on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-location, android-2.3-gingerbread

I downloaded an application which gives the latitude and longitude of the user and it gets information from GPS. Following code is there, it is working perfectly on Android 4.0.3 but on Android 2.3.3 it doesn't work. I tried both on emulators and devices. On Android 4.0.3 device and emulator, works perfect, but on Android 2.3.3 device and emulator doesn't work. This is the link of the project, that i downloaded from internet.
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html

Thanks for your helps.

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.lbs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LbsGeocodingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );

        retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCurrentLocation();
            }
        });        

    }    

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }   

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                    "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                    "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

This is logcat after sending coordinates to my 2.3.3 emulator

```
06-19 10:04:27.614: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed com.javacodegeeks.android.lbs/.LbsGeocodingActivity: +1s18ms
06-19 10:04:56.424: I/DEBUG(30): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-19 10:04:56.424: I/DEBUG(30): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3.3/GRI34/101070:eng/test-keys'
06-19 10:04:56.434: I/DEBUG(30): pid: 60, tid: 161  >>> system_server <<<
06-19 10:04:56.434: I/DEBUG(30): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
06-19 10:04:56.434: I/DEBUG(30):  r0 00000000  r1 40643f90  r2 41adff0c  r3 4689fc74
06-19 10:04:56.434: I/DEBUG(30):  r4 00000138  r5 00000000  r6 40643f90  r7 41adff0c
06-19 10:04:56.434: I/DEBUG(30):  r8 80701321  r9 80702240  10 00100000  fp 00000001
06-19 10:04:56.434: I/DEBUG(30):  ip ae20e7ec  sp 4689fc60  lr ae20acd7  pc ae207dfe  cpsr 00000030
06-19 10:04:56.694: I/DEBUG(30):          #00  pc 00007dfe  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
06-19 10:04:56.694: I/DEBUG(30):          #01  pc 0000acd2  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
06-19 10:04:56.704: I/DEBUG(30):          #02  pc 000012ca  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
06-19 10:04:56.704: I/DEBUG(30):          #03  pc 000014ae  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
06-19 10:04:56.714: I/DEBUG(30):          #04  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so
06-19 10:04:56.714: I/DEBUG(30):          #05  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so
06-19 10:04:56.714: I/DEBUG(30): code around pc:
06-19 10:04:56.714: I/DEBUG(30): ae207ddc ab04b082 9301cb04 6f646804 b00247a0 
06-19 10:04:56.724: I/DEBUG(30): ae207dec bc08bc10 4718b002 b510b40c ab04b082 
06-19 10:04:56.734: I/DEBUG(30): ae207dfc 6804cb04 34f89301 47a06824 bc10b002 
06-19 10:04:56.734: I/DEBUG(30): ae207e0c b002bc08 46c04718 b510b40c ab04b082 
06-19 10:04:56.734: I/DEBUG(30): ae207e1c 9301cb04 34986804 47a06824 bc10b002 
06-19 10:04:56.734: I/DEBUG(30): code around lr:
06-19 10:04:56.744: I/DEBUG(30): ae20acb4 91099008 f7fb6aa0 900aeab6 1c3a910b 
06-19 10:04:56.744: I/DEBUG(30): ae20acc4 6b646b23 930c1c28 1c31940d f7fd9b0f 
06-19 10:04:56.744: I/DEBUG(30): ae20acd4 4906f88f 44791c28 f7ff3150 b011fe1d 
06-19 10:04:56.754: I/DEBUG(30): ae20ace4 46c0bdf0 000043cc 00004148 00000786 
06-19 10:04:56.754: I/DEBUG(30): ae20acf4 f7fbb510 bd10ec24 4802b510 f7fb4478 
06-19 10:04:56.754: I/DEBUG(30): stack:
06-19 10:04:56.754: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc20  b295e9e2  
06-19 10:04:56.754: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc24  4092dccc  
06-19 10:04:56.764: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc28  00000009  
06-19 10:04:56.764: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc2c  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.764: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc30  0000ab90  [heap]
06-19 10:04:56.764: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc34  80048c1b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-19 10:04:56.764: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc38  0000ab90  [heap]
06-19 10:04:56.764: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc3c  4689fc6c  
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc40  00010004  [heap]
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc44  80037667  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc48  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc4c  afd0dcc4  /system/lib/libc.so
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc50  afb18a0c  /system/lib/libm.so
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc54  4689fe00  
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc58  df002777  
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc5c  e3a070ad  
06-19 10:04:56.774: I/DEBUG(30): #00 4689fc60  00000045  
06-19 10:04:56.785: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc64  ad331275  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-19 10:04:56.785: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc68  00000138  
06-19 10:04:56.785: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc6c  ae20acd7  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so
06-19 10:04:56.785: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc70  41adff0c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
06-19 10:04:56.785: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc74  00000001  
06-19 10:04:56.785: I/DEBUG(30): #01 4689fc78  6bea7b7c  
06-19 10:04:56.785: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc7c  40283d70  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc80  6bea7b7c  
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc84  40283d70  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc88  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc8c  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc90  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc94  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc98  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fc9c  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fca0  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.794: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fca4  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fca8  00c05100  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fcac  00000138  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fcb0  4689fe56  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fcb4  00000001  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fcb8  0000000a  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fcbc  4689fde8  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fcc0  00000000  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fcc4  807018d5  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fcc8  00000045  
06-19 10:04:56.804: I/DEBUG(30):     4689fccc  807012cd  /system/lib/hw/gps.goldfish.so
06-19 10:05:10.654: D/Zygote(32): Process 60 terminated by signal (11)
06-19 10:05:10.654: I/Zygote(32): Exit zygote because system server (60) has terminated
06-19 10:05:10.674: I/ActivityThread(233): Removing dead content provider: settings
06-19 10:05:10.674: I/ActivityThread(169): Removing dead content provider: settings
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'SurfaceFlinger' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'batteryinfo' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'usagestats' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'sensorservice' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'entropy' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'power' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'telephony.registry' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'account' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'content' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'package' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'activity' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'meminfo' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'cpuinfo' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'permission' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'hardware' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'battery' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'vibrator' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'alarm' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'window' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'statusbar' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'clipboard' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'device_policy' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'network_management' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'input_method' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'netstat' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'wifi' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'connectivity' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'throttle' died
06-19 10:05:10.684: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'accessibility' died
06-19 10:05:10.694: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'mount' died
06-19 10:05:10.694: I/ActivityThread(364): Removing dead content provider: settings
06-19 10:05:10.694: I/ActivityThread(131): Removing dead content provider: settings
06-19 10:05:10.704: I/ActivityThread(121): Removing dead content provider: settings
06-19 10:05:10.704: I/ActivityThread(126): Removing dead content provider: settings
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'notification' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'devicestoragemonitor' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'search' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'dropbox' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'wallpaper' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'location' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'uimode' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'audio' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'backup' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'appwidget' died
06-19 10:05:10.724: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'diskstats' died
06-19 10:05:10.734: E/installd(34): eof
06-19 10:05:10.734: E/installd(34): failed to read size
06-19 10:05:10.734: I/installd(34): closing connection
06-19 10:05:10.734: D/qemud(37): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 11
06-19 10:05:10.754: E/InputQueue-JNI(131): channel '4066e8c8 StatusBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
06-19 10:05:10.754: E/InputQueue-JNI(131): channel '4063ba90 TrackingView (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
06-19 10:05:10.834: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'isms' died
06-19 10:05:10.834: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'simphonebook' died
06-19 10:05:10.834: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
06-19 10:05:10.834: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'phone' died
06-19 10:05:10.855: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
06-19 10:05:10.855: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.audio_policy' died
06-19 10:05:10.855: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.player' died
06-19 10:05:10.855: I/ServiceManager(27): service 'media.camera' died
06-19 10:05:11.044: I/Netd(376): Netd 1.0 starting
06-19 10:05:11.894: D/AndroidRuntime(377): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
06-19 10:05:11.894: D/AndroidRuntime(377): CheckJNI is ON
06-19 10:05:12.274: I/(375): ServiceManager: 0xad50
06-19 10:05:12.274: D/AudioHardwareInterface(375): setMode(NORMAL)
06-19 10:05:12.285: I/CameraService(375): CameraService started (pid=375)
06-19 10:05:12.324: I/AudioFlinger(375): AudioFlinger's thread 0xc658 ready to run
06-19 10:05:12.964: I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(377): Profiler is disabled.
06-19 10:05:13.024: I/Zygote(377): Preloading classes...
```

Comment: could you provide a logcat of the device that is not working with the GPS

Comment: it is not my device, I am sending application and they are trying. When I send coordinates to emulator, emulator restarts itself and nothing happens

Comment: okay, then get the logcat for the emulator.

Comment: getLastKnownLocation(), may be giving you null location. This happens if gps provider do not have any location, for this on your device first run native apps like Navigation or Map application on device, and then run your application

Comment: edited my question.. @AnandTiwari this class has a locationlistener. in android 4.0.3, when i give a coordinate to emulator, it shows a toast message with new coordinates. but in 2.3.3 it doesn't work as expected

Comment: did you allow GPS support for your 2.3.3 emulator?

Comment: I don't think, your code have any problem.It looks correct you should create new emulator with gps enable, my previous comment is for real devices.

Comment: Yes. I allowed GPS support. When I go to emulator settings and disable GPS, the app shows a toast message, which says "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off". This works correcty but the coordinates not

Comment: @AnandTiwari I did it several times but the result is the same ! Have no idea what is going wrong. But in 4.0.3 emulator, it works perfectly and without a problem

Comment: I've tested you code with a 2.3.3 emulator, everything is working fine unless the GPS support is not there, where it will force the whole thing to restart. You might want to recreate the emulator with GPS Support

Comment: it doesn't work for me when I do that :S can you send a screen shot of your emulator edit page, so I can edit my emulator too. I know, I added GPS supprt, but I don't know :S

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064055/cant-get-geo-fixes-to-android-emulator), if you having same problem

Comment: @AnandTiwari It seems that is a bug, but how could you do that?

Comment: I dont have 2.3.3 real device, if you have then you can test your code but before running your app on your device first run native apps like Navigation or Map application (which uses gps location) on device, and then run your application and let me know if you still have same problem.

Comment: I tried on a real device but it is still not working :(

Comment: @AnandTiwari any solutiouns that you could find for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not add the following permission to your `Manifest.xml` :

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

You need this to be able to access user location.

Comment: I already did it. I have following permission blocks in my manifest file.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`